# Ideas for tracking the SI units of cell calculations?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create custom cell properties in Excel to achieve the following:

- Give all cells an "SI unit" property.
- Raw data cells can be manually given an SI unit
- Whenever you perform a formula calculation, the SI units of the input cells get combined based on defined rules - e.g. when multiplying, add the units, when adding, check the units are consistent.
- The end result is that the output of any complex calculations is easy to sense check by seeing if the units are correct (i.e. you can spot erroneous multiplications/divisions that have been made along the way)

I've done my research and found a few things on custom cell properties, but nothing that would achieve the above result.

If this add-on were to exist, it would be really useful for large-scale models in Excel which process lots of data. For instance, in complex economic models to calculate valuations such as the economic impact of releasing a kg of pollutant, simple errors like inadvertently multiplying by the same variable twice at different points in the computation are easily introduced. If you were able to inspect the units of each cell, which depends on the units of the cells which the formula within it references, then you could quickly spot and address this kind of issue.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think there is built-in functions to help you with that. You would probably need to parse the formula to know the dependent cells and their units, and then do some units calculations.

Comment: Would be an excellent add-on for Excel!

Comment: I just implemented a proof-of-concept way to do this in VBA. Use cell comments to store units in some standard format, e.g. `#m^1#s^-1` would be m/s. Define VBA functions that multiply, add, divide etc. cell values along with their units as stored in comments. For multiplication, unit dimensions are added. For addition, just check that they all match. etc. It's doable. But a bit of a pain.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about how the data will appear? And perhaps an example problem (formula calculation) you're trying to perform?

Comment: Hi Jean Francois - brilliant idea! Is there perhaps a different type of cell property that could be manipulated to store the SI units more discreetly? David Zemens - the example in question is a complex economic model with multiple spreadsheets, taking raw data such as land area and population as well as more technical data such as the value of a statistical life. The output is economic valuations such as the economic cost of a kg of SO2 released in Beijing. There are many intermediate stages and it is important to have confidence that the output is indeed in $/kg based on the inputs

Comment: If it's hidden how do you set its value? Comments seems to be a good place for this. Another solution would be using custom styles for each unit.

Comment: Yeah Fair point Z. However I wonder if there is a way of doing this without having to edit all of the functions you might want to use in a model, eg. index(), match(), average(), max(), min() etc.? E.G. a diagnostic which you can run which would go through the whole workbook and add comments to this effect. I've seen excel add-ons which can draw maps of all of the tabs showing which ones reference which, so there must be a way of looping through all cells and seeing which other cells they reference, then checking the comments on those cells etc. in a semi-efficient way.